# Execute a XQuery script directly from Gradle instead of from QConsole

Tags: gradle, xquery, marklogic, ml-gradle

I would like to execute a XQuery script directly from Gradle instead of from QConsole.
How to do that?

Is there a mlGradle task for that?  Or we could define a task like running MLCP from gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom task that extends the [ServerEvalTask](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/marklogic/gradle/task/ServerEvalTask.groovy).

As demonstrated in the [Custom tasks that talk to the Client REST API](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Writing-your-own-task#custom-tasks-that-talk-to-the-client-rest-api) WIKI page

```
task myXQueryTask(type: com.marklogic.gradle.task.ServerEvalTask) {
  xquery = "my XQuery code here"
}
```

If you are looking to read the contents of the code from a particular file, instead of a static string, then could instead do something like:

```
new File('/path/to/file').getText('UTF-8')
```

Comment: great thanks. It is what I am after ; ) 

1) Is it common (or ML recommended way) to use gradle to run Xquery code? 

2) **Corb2** is for data update and data reporting. I wonder Corb2 could be used for simple admin task like start ml db backup. 

3) With Gradle or Corb2, it is possible to implement **CI/CD** as they both could run in _terminal_.  Any other tools for ML **CI/CD**?

Again, great thanks.

Comment: CoRB also has a ModuleExecutor class that can be configured the same way as a CoRB job https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/wiki/ModuleExecutor-Tool. Whether you execute from shell scripts or gradle tasks to invoke CoRB classes or the ServerEvalTask, or something else to execute modules for CI/CD is your choice. Either would work fine.